# Visual Studio debugger not working consistently

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android app that we've been using for years now.  Recently, we started seeing a problem where we can't trace into or set breakpoints in certain methods/classes.  If I set a breakpoint, it doesn't stop at it and if I try to trace into it, it goes to a completely different area of the code.  This may be related to the fact that we recently had to enable Multi-Dex support, but I'm not sure if that is related.  I have several developer seeing the same problem.  We are using Visual Studio 2015.

I noticed that if I set the linker option to "Sdk and User assemblies", my debugging problems go away.  however, I then see crashes because it appears the linker is removing methods that are needed.

Comment: I'm sure you have already tried but have you cleared out all temp files and ensured you don't have any old copies of your code lying anywhere? Do you have pdb files for your app present?

Comment: Yes I deleted the whole bin and obj folders and did a clean and rebuild.

Comment: So do you have pdb files for your code?

Comment: Yes, there is a pdb file for each project in my solution in the bin\Debug folder

Comment: Do you have any information from the Output or Error list when doing a Debug/Deploy? Any error messages or anything that indicates failure?

Additionally, is this when deploying to physical devices or emulators or both?

Comment: @jWhite, I'm using physical devices.  I have not tried it on an emulator.  I don't see any errors in the output or Error list.

Comment: @P.Mancini Are you able to provide some sort of reproduction solution, and are you on the latest stable version of the Xamarin toolset?

Comment: @P.Mancini There are many things that could be happening here. I would highly advise that you add the following: A) Your Version Information B) A Diagnostic Build Output C) A Reproduction Project and optionally D) A small video clip that visually aides what you are describing here.